# Start/Stop background music button with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a single button which starts/stops background music in my iOS game. I can get it to play, but when I click it again, it just restarts instead of stopping. This is the code I use.

What am I doing wrong?

```
func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
        filename, withExtension: nil)
    if url == nil {
        println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }
    var error: NSError? = nil
    backgroundMusicPlayer =
        AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
        println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    if backgroundMusicPlayer.playing {
        backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0
    } else {
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `pause` instead of `stop`?  Alternatively, fetch the `currentTime` and then pass that to `playAtTime:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playBackgroundMusic` method is quite confusing. You create new `AVAudioPlayer` and assign it to `backgroundMusicPlayer`. Of course the new instance is not playing, so it starts to play each time you are calling this function.

You should create new `AVAudioPlayer` if current one is `nil`:

```
func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
            filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
            println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }
            var error: NSError? = nil
        backgroundMusicPlayer =
            AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
        if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
            println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
            return
        }
    }

    if(backgroundMusicPlayer.playing == true)
    {
        backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    }
}
```